# Securing endpoint with basic auth and additional conditions in springboot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I want to secure one endpoint with basic auth and allow requests only from specific IP addresses. Filter for basic auth:

```
SecurityFilterChain basicAuthSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                                               .requestMatchers("/test").authenticated()
                                               .anyRequest().permitAll()
                                      )
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic();

        return http.build();
    }
```

Filter for IP address:

```
SecurityFilterChain ipSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                                               .requestMatchers("/test").access(hasIpAddress("127.0.0.1"))
                                               .anyRequest().permitAll()
                                      )
                .csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }

private AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> hasIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
        IpAddressMatcher ipAddressMatcher = new IpAddressMatcher(ipAddress);
        return (authentication, context) -> {
            HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();
            return new AuthorizationDecision(ipAddressMatcher.matches(request));
        };
    }
```

Problem is with combining these solutions. With older Spring I could use

```
.access("isAuthenticated() and hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')")
```

but now this method accepts only AuthorizationManager instead of String.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper method that create an `AuthorizationManager` that match with certain IP:

```java
private AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> hasIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
    IpAddressMatcher ipAddressMatcher = new IpAddressMatcher(ipAddress);
    return (authentication, context) -> {
        HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();
        return new AuthorizationDecision(ipAddressMatcher.matches(request));
    };
}
```

Together with these static import :

```
import static org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager.authenticated;
import static org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorizationManagers.allOf;
```

You could then polish the codes to :

```java
http.authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers("/test").access(allOf(authenticated(), hasIpAddress("127.0.0.1")))
    .anyRequest().permitAll();
```